how to append one attribute with value
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editLicenseModal" class="edit-license" data-license-id="2" data-customer-id="11">Edit</a>

I want to append data-license-id="2" data-customer-id="11" attribute and values to
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="closeModal" onclick="editLicense()" data-license-id="" data-customer-id="">Edit License</button>

this tag
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="closeModal" onclick="editLicense()" data-license-id="2" data-customer-id="11">Edit License</button>


PS: Avoid using inline JS on* handlers like onclick="editLicense()". JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use addEventListener instead.



function editLicense() {
  const sourceElement = document.querySelector('.edit-license');
  const targetElement = document.querySelector('#closeModal');
  targetElement.dataset.licenseId = sourceElement.dataset.licenseId;
  targetElement.dataset.customerId = sourceElement.dataset.customerId;
}
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editLicenseModal" class="edit-license" data-license-id="2" data-customer-id="11">Edit</a>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="closeModal" onclick="editLicense()" data-license-id="" data-customer-id="">Edit License</button>




Uncaught ReferenceError: editLicense is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

@AashishASGGupta so you want to do this when clicking the button? put the code into the event handler, i've change the code.

Avoid using inline JS on* handlers like onclick="editLicense()". JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag or file. Use addEventListener instead.

This code gets all  tags with class="edit-license" containing data-bs-toggle="modal" and data-bs-target="#editLicenseModal" then imports params to button with id="closeModal".
Note: JavaScript must be placed after HTML code.


let btn=document.getElementById("closeModal");
document.querySelectorAll(".edit-license").forEach(function(item){
if(item.getAttribute('data-bs-toggle')=="modal" && item.getAttribute('data-bs-target')=="#editLicenseModal"){
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  buttonClick();
});
btn.setAttribute('data-license-id', item.getAttribute('data-license-id'));
btn.setAttribute('data-customer-id', item.getAttribute('data-customer-id'));
}
})


function buttonClick(){
alert(btn.getAttribute('data-license-id'));
alert(btn.getAttribute('data-customer-id'));
}

function editLicense(){
alert("inline onclick");
}
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editLicenseModal" class="edit-license" data-license-id="2" data-customer-id="11">Edit</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="closeModal" onclick="editLicense()">Edit License</button>





Remove the inline JS on* handler. JS should be in one place only
Use Element.dataset["someProperty"] = "value" to assign data   (or alternatively, using Object.assign())



// DOM utils
const el = (sel, par = document) => par.querySelector(sel);

// License 
addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elEditLicense = evt.target.closest(".edit-license");
  if (!elEditLicense) return;
  const elCloseModal = el("#closeModal");
  const { licenseId, customerId } = elEditLicense.dataset;
  Object.assign(elCloseModal.dataset, {licenseId, customerId});
});

addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elCloseModal = evt.target.closest("#closeModal");
  if (!elCloseModal) return;
  // TEST
  console.log(elCloseModal.dataset);
});
<a href="#"
  data-bs-toggle="modal"
  data-bs-target="#editLicenseModal"
  class="edit-license"
  data-license-id="2"
  data-customer-id="11">Edit</a>
  
<button type="button"
  class="btn btn-primary"
  id="closeModal"
  data-license-id=""
  data-customer-id="">Edit License</button>
 



Or alternatively, you could use Bootstrap Modal events and callback arguments to get the element caller data like in this example that uses jQuery
